# How can I hide and show the menu well so that it doesn't look messed up?

Tags: menu, display, show-hide

Hello The menu is hidden in mobile and tablet mode and can be accessed by pressing the toggle button. I did not change the appearance of my menu for tablet and mobile mode and it is only supposed to be lower and hidden, but when I click on the toggle button or resize, my content appears vertically. if display: none; If I delete it, the items will not be displayed in mobile and tablet mode. Thank you for your guidance.

```
//html 
<i class="zmdi zmdi-menu"></i>
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-6 pull-right rightmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="ghaleb.php"> قالب‌ها </a></li>
        <li><a href="gheymat.php"> تعرفه‌ها </a></li>
        <li><a href="nemoonekar.php"> نمونه‌کارها </a></li>
        <li><a> امکانات <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="emkanat.php"> امکانات و ویژگی‌ها </a></li>
                <li><a href="afzoone.php"> افزونه‌ها </a></li>
                <li><a href="damane.php"> دامنه اختصاصی </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a> خدمات <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sitesaz.php"> سایت ساز </a></li>
                <li><a href="frooshgahsaz.php"> فروشگاه ساز </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a> ادامه <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="academy.php"> آکادمی </a></li>
                <li><a href="rahnama.php"> راهنمای استفاده </a></li>
                <li><a href="tamas.php"> تماس با ما </a></li>
                <li><a href="weblog.php"> وبلاگ </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

// sass
  .rightmenu {
        position: relative;

    ul {
 
       @include displayflex($j-c: space-between);
       height: 60px;
       top: -30px;
       padding: 0px;

        @media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            background-color: white;
        }
    }
}

// js
$('.hidemenu').on('click',function(){
    $('.rightmenu ul').slideToggle(1000);
});

$(window).resize(function(e){
    if($(document).width()>992) {
        $('.rightmenu ul').css('display','block');
    } else {
      $('.rightmenu ul').css('display','none');
    }
});
```